# Limit wget wait time on non-responsive URL's

Tags: bash, web-scraping, wget

How do I limit the amount of time that wget spends waiting for a response to each URL?

This is the first time I've used bash so please forgive me if this is a basic question. I'm trying to download pictures of quails on image-net onto a virtual machine on Paperspace. The URL's of the images are listed here:

```
    http://image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n01804478
```

I'm using wget with the following command:

```
    wget -H -k -e robots=on -P ~/data/quails/train/cail_quail/ -i http://image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n01804478
```

I have found that there is at least one (perhaps more) URL's that does not respond and the recursion halts, waiting for a response. I'd like to skip those URL's after a short time (5 sec?).

An example of a URL that I need to skip:
        http://images.encarta.msn.com/xrefmedia/sharemed/targets/images/pho/t049/T049952B.jpg

Grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `wget` man page:

```
   -t number
   --tries=number
       Set number of tries to number. Specify 0 or inf for infinite retrying.  The default is to retry 20 times, with the exception of fatal errors like "connection refused" or "not found" (404), which are not retried.


   -T seconds
   --timeout=seconds
       Set the network timeout to seconds seconds.  This is equivalent to specifying --dns-timeout, --connect-timeout, and --read-timeout, all at the same time.

       When interacting with the network, Wget can check for timeout and abort the operation if it takes too long.  This prevents anomalies like hanging reads and infinite connects.  The only timeout enabled by default is a
       900-second read timeout.  Setting a timeout to 0 disables it altogether.  Unless you know what you are doing, it is best not to change the default timeout settings.

       All timeout-related options accept decimal values, as well as subsecond values.  For example, 0.1 seconds is a legal (though unwise) choice of timeout.  Subsecond timeouts are useful for checking server response times or
       for testing network latency.
```

So if you can do e.g.

```
wget -H -k -e robots=on -P ~/data/quails/train/cail_quail/ -i http://image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n01804478 -T 5 -t 1
```

It'll timeout after 5 seconds and not retry

Comment: Adding -T 5 results in successive retrying of the non-responsive URL's. I need to skip them altogether after a set amount of time.

Comment: Added `-t` flag, which specifies number of retries (default is 20, specify one to only try once)